# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'str' when making grid

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, typeerror

I'm new to python and tkinter and I've been getting the error below whenever I try and add custom grid sizes to my program. I'm pretty sure this isn't a duplicate thread as in all other threads, none of them involve a grid or utilize the grid function within their issue.

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'str' when making grid

The error I'm getting occurs whenever I try and change the vale of the GridSize within the GUI. You can change the value of it in the 'Change the settings of the treasure hunting game' part of the menu. I'm new to python so please put it in the simplest terms possible!

Here's my code:

```
import tkinter
import math
import random
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk



GridSizeSetByUser = '8x8'
choicesRows = ['8', '10', '12', '14']
v = choicesRows[0]
choicesColumns = ['8', '10', '12', '14']
v2 = choicesColumns[0]

GridRows = 9
GridColumns = 9


def getRows():
    global GridRows
    GridRows = GridRowSpinbox.get()
    print(GridRows)

def getColumns():
    global GridColumns
    GridColumns = GridColumnSpinbox.get()
    print(GridColumns)

def Treasure_Hunt_Window():
    THunt = tk.Tk()
    THunt.title("Treasure Hunt")
    THuntInstructions = "Find the treasure hidden deep in the sand!Use ye arrow keys to move around,\n\n then press Space to search that spot! Keep searching until ye find it!"
    board = GameBoard(THunt)
    board.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand="true", padx=4, pady=4)
    THunt.mainloop()

def Settings_Window():
    Settings = tk.Tk()
    Settings.title("Settings")
    SettingsWelcome = tk.Label(Settings, text='Settings Menu', width=50, fg="magenta")
    SettingsGridSize = tk.Label(Settings, text='Grid Size:', width =50, fg="magenta")
    global mystring
    mystring = StringVar()
    global mystring2
    mystring2 = StringVar()
    global GridRowSpinbox
    GridRowSpinbox = Spinbox(Settings, values=choicesRows, textvariable=mystring, width=50, state="readonly", fg="magenta")
    SaveRowSize = tk.Button(Settings, text='Save row size for grid', width=50, fg="magenta", command = getRows)
    global GridColumnSpinbox
    GridColumnSpinbox = Spinbox(Settings, values=choicesColumns, textvariable=mystring2, state="readonly", width=50, fg="magenta")
    SaveColumnSize = tk.Button(Settings, text='Save column size for grid', width=50, fg="magenta", command = getColumns)
    SettingsBandits = tk.Label(Settings, text='Amount of Bandits:', width =50, fg="magenta")
    BanditAmount = tk.Entry(Settings, width = 50, fg="magenta")
    SettingsBandits = tk.Label(Settings, text='Amount of Treasure Chests (up to 64)', width =50, fg="magenta")
    SettingsWelcome.pack(fill=X)
    SettingsGridSize.pack(fill=X)
    GridRowSpinbox.pack(fill=X)
    SaveRowSize.pack(fill=X)
    GridColumnSpinbox.pack(fill=X)
    SaveColumnSize.pack(fill=X)
    SettingsBandits.pack(fill=X)
    BanditAmount.pack(fill=X)



def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Menu")
    WelcomeButton = tk.Label(root, text='Welcome to the menu!', width=50, height=2, fg="magenta")
    WelcomeButton.pack(fill=X)
    StartButton = tk.Button(root, text='Start treasure hunting!', width=50, fg="magenta", command = Treasure_Hunt_Window)
    StartButton.pack(fill=X)
    SettingsButton = tk.Button(root, text='''Change the settings of the treasure hunting game.
This includes the grid size.''', width=50, fg="magenta", command = Settings_Window)
    SettingsButton.pack(fill=X)
    QuitButton = tk.Button(root, text='Exit the program', width=50, fg="magenta", command = root.destroy)# display message in a child window.
    QuitButton.pack(fill=X)
    root.mainloop()

def teststuff():
    print(GridRows)
    print(GridColumns)

class GameBoard(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, size=48, color1="white", color2="black"):
        '''size is the size of a square, in pixels'''

        self.rows = GridRows
        self.columns = GridColumns
        self.size = size
        self.color1 = color1
        self.color2 = color2
        self.pieces = {}

        canvas_width = GridColumns * size
        canvas_height = GridRows * size

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0,
                                width=canvas_width, height=canvas_height, background="green")
        self.canvas.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True, padx=2, pady=2)

        self.canvas.bind("<Configure>", self.refresh)


    def refresh(self, event):
        '''Redraw the board, possibly in response to window being resized'''
        xsize = int((event.width-1) / self.columns)
        ysize = int((event.height-1) / self.rows)
        self.size = min(xsize, ysize)
        self.canvas.delete("square")
        color = self.color2
        for row in range(self.rows):
            color = self.color1 if color == self.color2 else self.color2
            for col in range(self.columns):
                x1 = (col * self.size)
                y1 = (row * self.size)
                x2 = x1 + self.size
                y2 = y1 + self.size
                self.canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, outline="black", fill=color, tags="square")
                color = self.color1 if color == self.color2 else self.color2
        for name in self.pieces:
            self.placepiece(name, self.pieces[name][0], self.pieces[name][1])
        self.canvas.tag_raise("piece") 
        self.canvas.tag_lower("square")

main()
```

Comment: Always provide the full traceback of errors!

Comment: That error message can't possibly be the actual error message. I don't think any python error ever ends with something like "when making grid". "making" isn't part of the python exception vocabulary.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, it belongs to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC-by-SA license). If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-route-for-a-dissociation-request)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please continue working on your program, but replace your code with the following and work from there. You may also want to make it a practice to run your code through the [PEP8 online](http://pep8online.com/) website. Changes that were made to your code include ensuring that no errors or warnings were generated.

To answer your question, two of the functions down below do something slightly different from what your code originally did. Notice the first two functions, `get_rows` and `get_columns`. When getting information from a `Spinbox`, you need to convert the data into the correct type before using it.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk


GridSizeSetByUser = '8x8'
choicesRows = ['8', '10', '12', '14']
v = choicesRows[0]
choicesColumns = ['8', '10', '12', '14']
v2 = choicesColumns[0]

GridRows = 9
GridColumns = 9

my_string = my_second_string = grid_row_spinbox = grid_column_spinbox = None


def get_rows():
    global GridRows
    GridRows = int(grid_row_spinbox.get())
    print(repr(GridRows))


def get_columns():
    global GridColumns
    GridColumns = int(grid_column_spinbox.get())
    print(repr(GridColumns))


def treasure_hunt_window():
    t_hunt = tk.Tk()
    t_hunt.title("Treasure Hunt")
#     t_hunt_instructions = """\
# Find the treasure hidden deep in the sand!Use ye arrow keys to move around,
#
# then press Space to search that spot! Keep searching until ye find it!"""
    board = GameBoard(t_hunt)
    board.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand="true", padx=4, pady=4)
    t_hunt.mainloop()


def settings_window():
    global my_string, my_second_string, grid_row_spinbox, grid_column_spinbox
    settings = tk.Tk()
    settings.title("Settings")
    settings_welcome = tk.Label(settings, text='Settings Menu', width=50,
                                fg="magenta")
    settings_grid_size = tk.Label(settings, text='Grid Size:', width=50,
                                  fg="magenta")
    my_string = StringVar()
    my_second_string = StringVar()
    grid_row_spinbox = Spinbox(settings, values=choicesRows,
                               textvariable=my_string, width=50,
                               state="readonly", fg="magenta")
    save_row_size = tk.Button(settings, text='Save row size for grid',
                              width=50, fg="magenta", command=get_rows)
    grid_column_spinbox = Spinbox(settings, values=choicesColumns,
                                  textvariable=my_second_string,
                                  state="readonly", width=50, fg="magenta")
    save_column_size = tk.Button(settings, text='Save column size for grid',
                                 width=50, fg="magenta", command=get_columns)
    # settings_bandits = tk.Label(settings, text='Amount of Bandits:',
    #                             width=50, fg="magenta")
    bandit_amount = tk.Entry(settings, width=50, fg="magenta")
    settings_bandits = tk.Label(settings,
                                text='Amount of Treasure Chests (up to 64)',
                                width=50, fg="magenta")
    settings_welcome.pack(fill=X)
    settings_grid_size.pack(fill=X)
    grid_row_spinbox.pack(fill=X)
    save_row_size.pack(fill=X)
    grid_column_spinbox.pack(fill=X)
    save_column_size.pack(fill=X)
    settings_bandits.pack(fill=X)
    bandit_amount.pack(fill=X)


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Menu")
    welcome_button = tk.Label(root, text='Welcome to the menu!', width=50,
                              height=2, fg="magenta")
    welcome_button.pack(fill=X)
    start_button = tk.Button(root, text='Start treasure hunting!', width=50,
                             fg="magenta", command=treasure_hunt_window)
    start_button.pack(fill=X)
    settings_button = tk.Button(root, text='''\
Change the settings of the treasure hunting game.
This includes the grid size.''', width=50, fg="magenta",
                                command=settings_window)
    settings_button.pack(fill=X)
    # display message in a child window.
    quit_button = tk.Button(root, text='Exit the program', width=50,
                            fg="magenta", command=root.destroy)
    quit_button.pack(fill=X)
    root.mainloop()


def test_stuff():
    print(GridRows)
    print(GridColumns)


class GameBoard(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, size=48, color1="white", color2="black"):
        """size is the size of a square, in pixels"""

        self.rows = GridRows
        self.columns = GridColumns
        self.size = size
        self.color1 = color1
        self.color2 = color2
        self.pieces = {}

        canvas_width = GridColumns * size
        canvas_height = GridRows * size

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0,
                                width=canvas_width, height=canvas_height,
                                background="green")
        self.canvas.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True, padx=2, pady=2)

        self.canvas.bind("<Configure>", self.refresh)

    def refresh(self, event):
        """Redraw the board, possibly in response to window resize"""
        x_size = int((event.width-1) / self.columns)
        y_size = int((event.height-1) / self.rows)
        self.size = min(x_size, y_size)
        self.canvas.delete("square")
        color = self.color2
        for row in range(self.rows):
            color = self.color1 if color == self.color2 else self.color2
            for col in range(self.columns):
                x1 = (col * self.size)
                y1 = (row * self.size)
                x2 = x1 + self.size
                y2 = y1 + self.size
                self.canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, outline="black",
                                             fill=color, tags="square")
                color = self.color1 if color == self.color2 else self.color2
        for name in self.pieces:
            self.place_piece(name, self.pieces[name][0], self.pieces[name][1])
        self.canvas.tag_raise("piece")
        self.canvas.tag_lower("square")

    def place_piece(self, name, a, b):
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but thanks a load for this!

Comment: If you found the answer to be helpful, you may want to consider the recommendations given on this page: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Thanks for your support!